# Web-Приложения и Voip звонки

Tags: веб-программирование, voip

Доброго времени суток.

Есть web-сервис представляющий собой базу клиентов. Оператору требуется выбирать клиента и сразу же звонить ему по Voip.
Так же все поступающие звонки на данный номер должны отображаться в интерфейсе оператора и он должен их принимать.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: На хабре [обсуждалось][1]

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/119491/

Comment: К сожалениею флеш не подходит. Есть еще какие-то варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать sip uri. 
Номер делаете ссылкой по типу `<a href="sip:nomer@ip">`

В случае с использованием softphone то все просто, в настройках браузера сделать ассоциацию, после клика на данную ссылку браузер передаст softphone параметр (номер).

Пример работы с linphone

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] , после нажатия на такую ссылку браузер передает параметры linphone который в свою очередь выполняет вызов.

Какую АТС Вы используете ? Могу подсказать решения для конкретной АТС, можно обойтись использованием API АТС.